# Disable Do not display lock screen using powershell

Tags: group-policy, security-groups

Is there any Power shell command that changes the setting of the "Do not display lock screen" policy in Local group policy and i should perform the same on 30 machines.

Can i do it with a single command

Answer (score 0):

See the following question asked and answered on Stack Overflow. Whilst it's not exactly the same policy you're editing it should still work.

[Modify Local Security Policy using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23260656/modify-local-security-policy-using-powershell)